# Can't view app design in android studio preview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

My android studio's preview doesn't show any design that are code with text and also i can't see any design which are drag and draw from palette.
*Version* - **3.1.3** (build on June 5 2018)
[image]

Here is my activity_main.xml code. Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">    
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_Qty"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />    
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0" />    
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_Price" />    
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="$0"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />    
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="submitOrder"
    android:text="@string/btn_Order"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you paste your activity_main xml code

Comment: share your layout.xml and also see that red icon for error click on that icon find the error

Comment: @NileshRathod how to share my layout.xml. By the way, i am the beginner of android developer. Please be patient on me when I ask something wrong.

Comment: @Mr.Pyae i'm just asking for see that error you will get idea and also you can share your layout file by editing in your question thanks

Comment: @NileshRathod i add my activity_main.xml code in question. Please check for me

Comment: @Nabil mission complete!

Comment: @Mr.Pyae layout looks fine have click on that red icon to see error's

Comment: Try to close and reopen preview